# ZK: Modal window not working properly when exception is thrown

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, zk

The problem I have is pictured in [this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/d81hea/3-DoModal-wth-Exception) I created:

If you click on the Order coffee button, I've forced a Runtime Exception to be thrown within the doAfterCompose method of the modal window's controller. As you can see the modal window gets appended at the bottom of the page. This, aside from being ugly, allows the user to click again the Order Cofee button, which causes the famous "Not unique ID in space" error.

Is there any way to prevent the window from being created when an Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setPage(null)` method on your component.

Comment: I don't think I understand, can you apply it on the fiddle I posted?

Comment: Of course. See [this](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/108h613/3-DoModal-wth-Exception#source-4) fork.

Comment: that seems to fix it, drawback is I have to do this for every dialog I use (and I have lots!). Thanks!

Comment: you could abstract it for the future changes :  http://zkfiddle.org/sample/108h613/5-DoModal-wth-Exception